# C++ Linked List segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c

I'm getting a segmentation fault in the removeElement() function. _buckets is
an array of HashTableVoidEntry pointers. This project is supposed to implement
a simple hash table that stores names.

GDB is telling me that the "else" line in this else block in the
removeElement() function is where it crashes. Can anyone pinpoint the problem
please? I have no idea how to fix this. I'm trying to set up conditions to
check where the element is at in the linked list. The first "if" block tells me
if the element I want to remove is at the head. The "else if" block tells me if
it's at the end, and the else block is for anywhere else in the list. I'm still
learning linked lists so I'm sure I'm making a stupid error.

```
    else
    {
        prev->_next = e->_next;
        delete e;
        return true;
    }
EleHashTableVoid::HashTableVoid()
{
    _buckets = (HashTableVoidEntry**)malloc(TableSize * sizeof(HashTableVoidEntry*));
    for(int i = 0; i < TableSize; i++)
    {
        _buckets[i] = NULL;
    }
}
// Removes an element in the hash table. Return false if key does not exist.
bool HashTableVoid::removeElement(const char * key)
{
    int h = hash(key);
    HashTableVoidEntry * e = _buckets[h];
    HashTableVoidEntry * prev = NULL;
    while((e != NULL) && (strcmp(key, e->_key) != 0))
    {
        prev = e;
        e = e->_next;
    }
    if(e != NULL)
    {
        if(prev == NULL)
        {
            if(e == _buckets[h])
            {
                _buckets[h] = e -> _next;
                delete e;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(e -> _next == NULL)
        {
            prev->_next = NULL;
            delete e;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->_next = e->_next;
            delete e;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine, maybe the data is already corrupted by the time you call that function?

Comment: I haven't used gcc in a while for C++, but have you checked if NULL is defined? It doesn't need to be for C++ - it's better to compare to 0.

Comment: Not to insult your intelligence, but is each `HashTableVoidEntry` object individually allocated with `new HashTableVoidEntry` ?

Comment: It might not be the crash you're seeing right now, but one error is that you don't remove 'e' from _buckets in the 'else if' or 'else' clauses.  So you end up with a dangling pointer in _buckets and your code will crash if you do anything with it.

Comment: I don't understand, what do I have to do? Should I not be using "delete"?

Comment: @adpalumbo: there seems to be a clause that sets the bucket to e->next if e is actually in the bucket; I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: make sure you compile the code without any optimization or else GDB will behave strangely.

Comment: This is a project for school and we're given test scripts. One of the tests that uses this function isn't passing so that's how I know this function is the problem.

Comment: Ernest is right.  I was misinterpreting how you designed this.  You can disregard what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems with this code, but could you accidentally hash an item twice?

BTW, you don't need the `else if` clause, as it is basically the same, as the `else` clause.

Comment: I have another function that handles duplicates. That works fine, so I don't see that being a problem.

Comment: What do you mean the `else if` is basically a `else`?

Comment: Both of those blocks of code basically perform the same function.

Comment: If you store a pointer to the const string (key) in the Element itself, could you delete it (in destructor)?